# module decouple not found when running Python script through Node endpoint on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, package.json, pipenv

My project runs an image transcription script when people submit an image through my submission route.

It works just fine locally using the following dev script and the command `pipenv run yarn dev` :

```
"scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "start": "pipenv run node build/index.js",
        "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
        "test": "jest --watch",
        "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -f src/ormconfig.ts",
        "typeorm-dev": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -c development -f src/ormconfig.ts",
        "connection": "ts-node src/util/get-connection.ts"
    },
```

Though, the start script doesn't seem to build the virtualenv correctly on Heroku.

Buildpacks are installed. Python first, then Node.

In the logs it looks like it builds fine

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Need to update SQLite3, clearing cache
-----> Installing python-3.7.6
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
       Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (8b8885)…
-----> Installing SQLite3
Sqlite3 successfully installed.
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.16.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.13.4
       Resolving yarn version 1.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.0)...
       Installed yarn 1.22.0

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.22.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       success Already up-to-date.
       Done in 0.72s.

-----> Build
       Running build (yarn)
       yarn run v1.22.0
       $ tsc
       Done in 14.12s.

-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       yarn install v1.22.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
       Done in 19.59s.

-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 113.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v28
       https://***.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

It also installs SQLite for some reason. :: shrugs ::

This is my Pipfile.

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
google-cloud-datastore = "*"
google-cloud-vision = "*"
python-decouple = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
pyinstaller = "*"
python-datauri = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Here's how decouple is being imported in my script.

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
from json import loads, dumps
from decouple import config
from datauri import DataURI
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
# from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth import compute_engine
import os
```

This is the heroku log when I attempt to submit an image through the node endpoint.

```
2020-03-03T14:00:23.367559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/submissions" host=***.herokuapp.com request_id=4cc77332-3f0f-4208-bc48-804644b7bf64 fwd="***" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=204 bytes=315 protocol=https
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460776+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:288
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460788+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460788+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460789+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460789+00:00 app[web.1]: PythonShellError: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decouple'
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460790+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PythonShell.parseError (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:260:21)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460790+00:00 app[web.1]:     at terminateIfNeeded (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:139:32)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:131:13)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460792+00:00 app[web.1]:     ----- Python Traceback -----
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460792+00:00 app[web.1]:     File "src/util/scripts/transcription.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460792+00:00 app[web.1]:       from decouple import config
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460793+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on PythonShell instance at:
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460794+00:00 app[web.1]:     at terminateIfNeeded (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:153:26)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460794+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:131:13)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460795+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460795+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12) {
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460795+00:00 app[web.1]:   traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n' +
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460796+00:00 app[web.1]:     '  File "src/util/scripts/transcription.py", line 3, in <module>\n' +
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460796+00:00 app[web.1]:     '    from decouple import config\n' +
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460797+00:00 app[web.1]:     "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decouple'\n",
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460797+00:00 app[web.1]:   executable: 'python3',
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460798+00:00 app[web.1]:   options: null,
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460798+00:00 app[web.1]:   script: 'src/util/scripts/transcription.py',
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460798+00:00 app[web.1]:   args: null,
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460799+00:00 app[web.1]:   exitCode: 1
2020-03-03T14:00:23.460799+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-03-03T14:00:23.470279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-03-03T14:00:23.470482+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-03-03T14:00:23.471369+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! ***@0.0.1 start: `pipenv run node build/index.js`
2020-03-03T14:00:23.471528+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-03-03T14:00:23.471653+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-03-03T14:00:23.471736+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the ***e@0.0.1 start script.
2020-03-03T14:00:23.471813+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-03-03T14:00:23.476689+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-03T14:00:23.477045+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-03-03T14:00:23.477046+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-03-03T14_00_23_472Z-debug.log
2020-03-03T14:00:23.578883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-03-03T14:00:23.583792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Comment: What about other modules like google.cloud and datauri? Are they also not found? You only see errors for decople since it is first. If Same error exists for other packages there must be something wrong with install script. Maybe try installing python dependancies via pip and requirements.txt.

Comment: They are also not found, yeah.

If I comment out decouple, it just moves on to datauri being not found.

Ok, I'll try it that way. 

It's weird though, it looks like it builds just fine. :: shrugs ::

Comment: Yes it builds jsut fine because python is an interpreted language and non sintactic errors will come to light only when you run a program.

Comment: Just in case here is a reference link for the mentioned install procedure: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the solution was to add a `Procfile` with the following line:
`web: yarn start`

Then alter my package.json start script: `"start": "node build/index.js",`

Then, I created a `requirements.txt` file and added all dependencies:

```
altgraph>=0.17
cachetools>=4.0.0
certifi>=2019.11.28
chardet>=3.0.4
future>=0.18.2
google-api-core>=1.16.0
google-auth>=1.11.2
google-cloud-core>=1.3.0
google-cloud-datastore>=1.11.0
google-cloud-vision>=1.0.0
googleapis-common-protos>=1.51.0
grpcio>=1.27.2
idna>=2.9
joblib>=0.14.1
numpy>=1.18.1
pandas>=1.0.1
pefile>=2019.4.18
protobuf>=3.11.3
pyasn1>=0.4.8
pyasn1-modules>=0.2.8
PyInstaller>=3.6
Pyphen>=0.9.5
python-datauri>=0.2.8
python-dateutil>=2.8.1
python-decouple>=3.3
python-dotenv>=0.12.0
pytz>=2019.3
pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0
requests>=2.23.0
rsa>=4.0
scikit-learn>=0.22.1
scipy>=1.4.1
six>=1.14.0
textstat>=0.6.0
urllib3>=1.25.8
```